# UITableView max size while respecting autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, intrinsic-content-size

So what i want to do is to have a tableview that maxes out it sizes while respecting autolayout constraints. Right now i have a tableview that maxes out it is size, but its not scrollable.

```
public class ExpandingTableView2: UITableView {

    override public func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if !self.bounds.size.equalTo(self.intrinsicContentSize) {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()

        }
    }

    override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        let intrinsicContentSize = super.contentSize
        return intrinsicContentSize
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of maxing out the tableview size, which will make it non scrollable as the tableview size will be equal to content size, make you `tableview` width and height equal to the superview.

Comment: The tableview can also be very small, sometimes only one line. Then i don't want it to be maxed out

Comment: Increasing tableview size is a really bad idea. Ideally a tableview will have the size which fits inside the screen. The compiler has no sense of what is visible to you and what is not. So when you increase the size of the table view, it'll go outside the visible area rendering the content at the bottom hidden and not accessible since the contentsize is within the tableview size, just that it is not visible to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the tableview height based on the content size by creating an outlet for height contraint:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableViewHeightConstraint.constant != tableView.contentSize.height && tableViewHeightConstraint.constant < view.frame.height // This will prevent to increase tableview height beyond the view and let it scroll
{
        setupHeightConstraintForTableView(tableView.contentSize.height)
    }

   // rest of the code
}

func setupHeightConstraintForTableView(_ heightValue: CGFloat) {
    tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = heightValue
    self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Your logic is correct, but in your implementation if there is something other than the tableview in the view, this wouldn't work. You might want to check if the view goes outside in some other way.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri i completely agree it needs some refactoring if there is any other subview is also included other than the tableview. But as per the question it had only tableview.  if any subviews are there we need to put conditions accordingly based on their positions.

Comment: The tableview is inside another view that has a height constraint based on screen height and some labels heights.

Comment: @TommySadiqHinrichsen give if condition based on that superview.

Comment: Also if you meant the height of the view, it should be `view.frame.height`? And not sure if `updateConstraintsIfNeeded()` triggers a layout update. I've only seen `layoutIfNeeded()` used.

Comment: Correct thanx for pointing. I edited it to `view.frame.height`.

Comment: Althought this was not 100 % the solution i ended up, it is what got me looking in the right direction.

Comment: @TommySadiqHinrichsen glad that i could help

Answer (score 0):

What is important here is to keep the constraints that govern the max height of the tableview higher than the constraints used to set its height. I also set the content compression resistance of the tableview to 250.

```
public class ExpandingTableView: UITableView {

    @IBOutlet public weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override public func reloadData() {

        guard let heightConstraint = self.heightConstraint, heightConstraint.priority.rawValue < 750  else { return }

        var height: CGFloat = 0.0
        for section in 0..<(self.dataSource?.numberOfSections?(in: self) ?? 1) {
            for row in 0..<(self.dataSource?.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: section) ?? 0) {
                let rowHeight = (self.delegate?.tableView?(self, heightForRowAt: IndexPath(row: row, section: section))) ?? self.rowHeight
                height += rowHeight
            }
        }

        heightConstraint.constant = height

        super.reloadData()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }

}
```